# Many SCSS/SASS files to one CSS file?

Tags: html, css, sass

Is it possible to make sass listen to a directory with many sass files and generate one CSS file? I have found a way by including many sass files into one (style.scss):

```
@import "scss/header";
@import "scss/footer";
```

And then run the following code:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css
```

but the problem is that I have to change that file before I generate a new CSS file.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

If you watch the directory, sass will be able to notice changes in @imported files, and update dependent files.

style.scss:

```
@import "header";
@import "footer";
```

And do:

```
sass --watch .
```

It will compile all files in the directory to .css; ignoring files whose name start with a `_`.

I you modify _header.scss or _footer.scss, if will update style.scss too.

You can also output in an other directory:

```
sass --watch .:output_dir/
```

Comment: Would you please clarify? the "header" and "footer" are they header.scss? or header.css? and are they in a subfolder or the same folder as screen.scss?

Comment: What if the partials are in a different folder? I have that situation and can't move my css-Files because I would have to make lots of changes in that case. Is it still possible to change a partial and afterwards a new css main file is created?

Comment: Helps to me, Thanks

Comment: Long shot here, I know this answer is older than dirt but has there been any updates to where it will NOT create a separate `.css`? It's great that it will write to your single `.css` file but it also creates a NEW `.css` file in the process.

Answer (score 5):

You can tell SASS to watch an entire folder with:

```
sass --watch application/sass:public/stylesheets
```

If you import all your partial files, this should generate one file. Every time you edit a file in the folder, the CSS files will be generated automatically.

Comment: that would work to, both solutions is nice. But my goal was to just one CSS file in total and with _ and one scss file that includes everything else was the best solution for me. Thanks for the answer, after 2 days with sass I really like it with all its features!

Answer (score 4):

I was having quite a frantic googling session trying to resolve this issue.
Turns out it's quite simple if you're using Rictwick Live Sass Compiler on VS Code.

1. Make sure to save your sass/scss files starting with an underscore eg: _variables.scss, _mixin.scss.
2. @import them into the main style.scss file you want to compile. Eg:

   ```
   @import "_mixins";
   @import "_variables";
   ```
3. Pretty much that's it, you've compiled all your .scss files into a single CSS file.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add,
You can also call Variables ($) and Mixins from other files.

For Example:

*_variable.scss* = `$primary:#000` 
*_header.scss* = `header {color:$primary;}` 
*_footer.scss* = `footer {background:$primary}`

**custom.scss**:

```
@import "_variables.scss";
@import "_header.scss";
@import "_footer.scss";
```

**Output = custom.css**

```
header {color:#000;}
footer {background:#000;}
```