# Sass: Watch multiple input-files for one output-file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using SASS on windows doing something like:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css --style compressed
```

This works fine so far.

Now I got the problem that style.scss is including some other scss-files, but when these included files are changed, the watch-command doesn't rebuild style.css.

I found that you could do something like:

```
sass --watch style.scss:style.css style2.scss:style2.css --style compressed
```

but I don't want to get a style2.css, because the only CSS should be in style.css.

So I think I need something like:

```
sass --watch style.scss,style2.css:style.css --style compressed
```

Any ideas how to do it?

Added: I think it's not quite a duplicate of [how to watch changes in whole directory/folder containing many sass files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427849/how-to-watch-changes-in-whole-directory-folder-containing-many-sass-files)
because the command:

```
sass --watch sass:css
```

results in all files in /sass/ are compiled to single files in /css/, which means:

```
/sass/style.scss becomes /css/style.css
/sass/style2.scss becomes /css/style2.css
/sass/style3.scss becomes /css/style3.css
etc.
```

What I need is:

```
Changing /sass/style.scss results in recompiling /sass/style.scss to /css/style.scss
Changing /sass/style2.scss results in recompiling /sass/style.scss to /css/style.scss
Changing /sass/style3.scss results in recompiling /sass/style.scss to /css/style.scss
```

Comment: Alternate duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307456/many-scss-sass-files-to-one-css-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31311147/underscore-in-partial-sass-file

Comment: Why would you expect style3.scss to force style.scss to recompile?