# Sass not finding correct filepaths

Tags: css, sass

I want to use sass to write individual components, for example styling a chart. But I don't want to manually include every component, but rather have one scss file that includes all the components and then gets compiled to one `.css` file that I can include. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307456/many-scss-sass-files-to-one-css-file) SO answer but it didn't work for me and according to SASS, [you're not supposed to use `@import` anymore](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import). This is the project structure:

```
src/
├─ about/
│  ├─ .../
│  ├─ scss/
│  │  ├─ chart.scss/
├─ app/
│  ├─ scss/
├─ build/
│  ├─ css/
|  |  ├─ styles.css
├─ base/
│  ├─ styles.scss
```

`styles.scss` should include all scss files from all projects in the src, and should be compiled on every .scss save. When I do it with this command though:

`sass base/styles.scss:build/css/main.css --watch --style=compressed --no-source-map`

it gives the error:

```
Error: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "//about/scss/chart.scss";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  base_templates\styles.scss 1:1  root stylesheet
```

The content of `styles.scss` is

```scss
@use "//about/scss/chart.scss";
```

and that of `chart.scss`:

```css
h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
```

(as a test). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path should be "/src/about/scss/chart.scss" for Sass if src is the source of the volume respectively partition. Sass never 'knows' anything about your domain or network, therefore you can't assume that you can use paths based on the webroot as absolute paths.

You can also consider using relative paths, then it would be '../about/scss/chart.scss'.